# Cannot deploy KIE Server 7.70 on wildfly

Tags: jboss, wildfly, optaplanner, drools-kie-server

I have been trying to install the latest version of KIE Workbench and execution server. However, I have been unable to get the KIE execution server deployed on wildfly, incurring the following error:

```
2018-05-29 21:42:07,913 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/kie-server-controller-standalone-7.7.0.Final-ee7' for server 'default-server'
2018-05-29 21:42:20,751 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in /C:/Users/jerem/Downloads/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/bin/content/kie-server-7.7.0.Final-ee7.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2018-05-29 21:42:20,754 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jaxb-core.jar in /C:/Users/jerem/Downloads/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/bin/content/kie-server-7.7.0.Final-ee7.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2018-05-29 21:42:20,816 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in /C:/Users/jerem/Downloads/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/bin/content/kie-server-7.7.0.Final-ee7.war/WEB-INF/lib/serializer-2.7.1.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2018-05-29 21:42:20,822 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry xercesImpl.jar in /C:/Users/jerem/Downloads/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/bin/content/kie-server-7.7.0.Final-ee7.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2018-05-29 21:42:20,822 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in /C:/Users/jerem/Downloads/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/bin/content/kie-server-7.7.0.Final-ee7.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2018-05-29 21:42:20,822 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry serializer.jar in /C:/Users/jerem/Downloads/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/bin/content/kie-server-7.7.0.Final-ee7.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2018-05-29 21:42:20,847 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."kie-server-7.7.0.Final-ee7.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."kie-server-7.7.0.Final-ee7.war".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "kie-server-7.7.0.Final-ee7.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:172)
    at org.jboss.msc//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
    at org.jboss.msc//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found
    at org.jboss.msc//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.getRequiredService(ServiceContainerImpl.java:669)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.getDefaultResourceAdapterName(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:274)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processMessageBeans(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:154)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processAnnotations(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.processAnnotations(AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.deploy(AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.server//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
    ... 5 more

2018-05-29 21:42:20,851 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "kie-server-7.7.0.Final-ee7.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"kie-server-7.7.0.Final-ee7.war\".PARSE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"kie-server-7.7.0.Final-ee7.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found"}}
2018-05-29 21:42:20,868 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "kie-server-router-proxy-7.7.0.Final.jar" (runtime-name : "kie-server-router-proxy-7.7.0.Final.jar")
2018-05-29 21:42:20,870 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "kie-server-controller-standalone-7.7.0.Final-ee7.war" (runtime-name : "kie-server-controller-standalone-7.7.0.Final-ee7.war")
2018-05-29 21:42:20,870 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "kie-server-7.7.0.Final-ee7.war" (runtime-name : "kie-server-7.7.0.Final-ee7.war")
2018-05-29 21:42:20,874 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."kie-server-7.7.0.Final-ee7.war".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "kie-server-7.7.0.Final-ee7.war"

2018-05-29 21:42:20,947 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
2018-05-29 21:42:20,950 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
2018-05-29 21:42:20,952 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
2018-05-29 21:42:20,953 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 11.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) started (with errors) in 28119ms - Started 450 of 680 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 356 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: 7.7.x prefers Wildfly 11.0, FWIW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KIE Execution Server (EE7 distribution) has a JMS interface which depends on WildFly's messaging subsystem. WildFly has a number of profiles configured in `wildfly-11.0.0.Final/standalone/configuration/standalone-*.xml` files. Only "full" profiles have the messaging subsystem configured.

To fix your issue, start WildFly with `-c standalone-full.xml`. For example

```
$ ./bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml
```

Without the `-c` option, WildFly uses `standalone.xml` profile, which doesn't have messaging subsystem configured.

Comment: During bootstrap, can we detect that the messaging subsystem is absent and throw a better error message (and if possible chain the original exception)? I am thinking of an error message like "... messaging subsystem is abscent ...\n  Maybe you're not using a full web profile of WildFly." If so, please make a jira.